# Pass parameter to EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I need to connect to few databases whos look the same. I want to pass ConnectionString name as parameter when I induce instance of DB connection.

Context Class

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppDbContext(string test) : base(GetOptions(test))
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Cargo> Cargoes { get; set; }

        

        private static DbContextOptions GetOptions(string connectionString)
        {
            return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString).Options;
        }

    }
```

Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
```

Code

```
[HttpGet]
        public Cargo Get()
        {
            var test2 = new AppDbContext("TEST");
            return _appDbContext.Cargoes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code == "code");
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

I think it's better to create a separate context:

```
public class AnotherContext : AppDbContext 
{
 
}
```

And now you can configure them:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FirstConnStr")));

services.AddDbContext<AnotherContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecondConnStr")));
```

Comment: And if you need to connect to 10 different databases with the same structure? How about 50? Or 100? And yes, I have seen that pattern before.

Comment: @DavidG do u know how to solve my problem?